# EXCEL: COUNTIFS with multiple criteria and or logic

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Attempting to count a named range "STATUS" if the value of the cells equals Reserved, Blocked, Pending OR Archive with multiple other countif criteria.

Everything else works, but the array formula I used for counting the status is only returning a count if the cell value = Reserved.

Here is the formula I'm using:

=(COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A3,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A3,1),AGENT,"TEST",COMPANY,"TEST",STATUS,{"Reserved","Blocked","Pending","Archive"}))

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Us Sum to countifs

```
=SUM((COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A3,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A3,1),AGENT,"TEST",COMPANY,"TEST",STATUS,{"Reserved","Blocked","Pending","Archive"})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using =OR logic.. Replace the following for your STATUS portion

```
OR(STATUS="Reserved", STATUS="blocked, STATUS="Pending", STATUS="Archive")
```

EDIT:

Since the previous advice did not work, try this:

```
(COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A3,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A3,1),AGENT,"TEST",COMPANY,"TEST",STATUS,OR("Reserved", "Blocked", "Pending", "Archive"))
```

Comment: placing the OR before the criteria range produces an error message. I placed it before the criteria and that didn't work either, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: EDIT - I tried placing the OR after the criteria range after your first suggestion and I still received an error message.

Comment: Did you try the exact code I included in the recent edit?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT((DATES>=A3)*(DATES<EDATE(A3,1))*(AGENT="TEST")*(COMPANY="TEST")*((STATUS="Reserved")+(STATUS="Blocked")+(STATUS="Pending")+(STATUS="Archive")))`

It would be great if you could provide some sample data or even a screenshot of your sheet.

Comment: I tried this out and received an error message. I cannot provide sample data or screenshots at this time, much of the information is proprietary. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: This needs to be entered as an array formula to work.