# Using COUNTIFS with and&or logic across multiple columns without double counting rows

Tags: excel, countif, formulas

Newcomer to Excel formulas here! Before making my own post, I looked at posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655685/using-or-and-in-countifs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954394/excel-countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic) but they deal with looking for multiple possible values in one column, rather than one value across multiple columns.

I have a list of projects worked on by a team of developers, each with a priority assigned to it. The developers can be the project requester, the assignee responsible for the project's completion, or an assignee for one task on the project. One developer may fill multiple roles within the same project, but two developers from the team will not work on the same project. "Someone" just means a developer from a different team.

[Example sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpYjG.jpg)

I am trying to tabulate how many projects of a specific priority, or range of priorities, each developer works on (in any capacity), without counting any row twice. My first guesses were to use

```
COUNTIFS(F:F,">=2",{E:E,"Dev1",I:I,"Dev1",K:K,"Dev1",M:M,"Dev1"})
```

or

```
COUNTIFS(F:F,">=2",D:N,"Dev1")
```

but no dice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your question.  Do you mind to show an expected results and I will do my best to help?

Comment: Try https://excelxor.com/2015/03/30/counting-rows-where-at-least-one-condition-is-met/. Give me a shout if there's anything you need clarifying.

Comment: @XORLX that's exactly what I need! Thank you! EDIT: I wish you'd posted that as an answer so I could upvote it :D

Comment: You're welcome! Not sure it's considered acceptable to post links as an answer on this site, but thanks in any case!